# How to set up multiple sites using one database on Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, mobile-website

Been round the web trying to sort this out, lots of info on pre D7 versions. but D7 just seems to point to the sites.php file.

I would like to have a "example.com" and "m.example.com" this would be for normal and mobile phone versions. at the moment I have this kind of structure.

local windows install using xampp.

- c:\xampp\htdocs\example\all my Drupal site files
- e.g.
- c:\xampp\htdocs\example\sites\all\themes\example\
- c:\xampp\htdocs\example\sites\all\modules\example\

My webserver

- /public_html/all my Drupal site files
- e.g.
- /public_html/sites/all/themes/example/
- /public_html/sites/all/modules/example/

this site all works by accessing www.example.com

so now Id like to create a new theme (and maybe new modules) to run for my subdomain www.m.example.com
I setup my subdomain using CPanel and it created the m folder under /public_html/ 
e.g. 
/public_html/m

I'd like to configure a working setup for my local machine and a published website setup for the www.m.example.com site.

I've tried configuring the sites.php file but am confused by the examples and its use.

So please if you could help me out here, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is change your structure a bit. The sites directory in Drupal can be used to house your various sites. As you would imagine, the "all" directory is a directory that would be shared between all instances. You should set up your sites and directories like this.
drupal/sites/all
drupal/sites/example.com
drupal/sites/m.example.com
In these directories, you can have site specific modules and themes, and settings.php. If you want the sites to use the same DB, just duplicate the settings.php into both sites folders.
If needed you can use the sites.php to set up directory aliases.

Comment: thats great advice, although on trying it out I now realise I have no idea how the sites.php is supposed to work against localhost. I have raised a new SO question about it here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038917/drupal-7-trying-to-use-site-php-to-redirect-localhost-requests

Comment: I've figured out the hosts file redirect now, but I cannot get Drupal to use different folders? I've setout the structure as you mentioned above, with different CSS (to make it obvious) but both sites look exactly the same, so I assume its not being redirected? any thing I missed you think?

Comment: sorry, for whatever reason I didn't know you commented again until now. Most likely it's because you are sharing the db. That means, any change you make in one site will directly affect the other one and will look like a mirror. If you are interested in creating a mobile version of your site, definitely recommend checking out the [mobile tools module](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools)